# sp_executesql Causes Undesired Implicit Conversion

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been suffering from this for a while now. In SQL Server Profiler, I confirmed that using `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` produces a `sp_executesql` command. Sometimes, the query takes too long to execute, the cause used to be one of the following two cases:

1. All of my text database fields are `varchar`. We know that `sp_executesql` only accepts `unicode` types (`nvarchar`, `nchar`). Specifying `SqlDbType.Varchar` for the parameter type in C# sometimes causes a big performance problem (for certain queries) because of the fact that an implicit conversion takes place in order to convert the `varchar` parameter to the `nvarchar` needed for `sp_executesql`. Aparently, that conversion was taking place on every row scan.
2. So I specified `SqlDbType.NVarChar` instead and the problem is solved temporarily. One day, I ended up having the same performance problem (for a different query) for the same cause but in another way. An implicit conversion was taking place to convert all the `varchar` values in the specified database column to `nvarchar`. Reverting the type to `SqlDbType.VarChar` fixed the problem for that case.

I know the problem is not due to Parameter Sniffing because I tried using `sp_updatestats` to refresh the cached plans and using `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to make sure a new plan gets generated. But that did not solve the problem.
I cannot wrap my head around this and I wish to avoid using `sp_executesql` altogether if possible. Any idea how to avoid the undesired implicit conversions?

EDIT: It's worth noting that the queries that are generated are dynamic (coming from a query builder feature). Also, it's worth noting that the problem only showed when a "contain" operand (in sql: `like %%`) was used.

EDIT: [This](http://www.sqlconsulting.com/news1309.htm) good article emphasizes the same problem. However, he author sadly declares that there is no solution.. yet, hopefully.

Comment: Show the code. It is certainly possible to pass a `varchar` parameter using  `sp_executesql`.

Comment: I know it's possible. Per my last edit, I emphasized that the scenarios belong to a "query builder" feature in which all queries and parameters are dynamically generated. Meaning that there is no specific SQL query that causes the problem to happen. That's why I didn't show the code. It's not a specific sql query-related issue. It's rather

Comment: Well the way to avoid implicit conversions is to pass parameters of the correct datatype. If the query builder doesn't do that it is broken.

Comment: It's exactly as @MartinSmith said. There is nothing preventing `varchar` parameters from being used with `sp_executesql`. They don't get implicitly converted to `nvarchar` unless they are used in a context that forces it, such as comparing an `nvarchar` database column to a `varchar` parameter. And in that case, it should be obvious to you that it would be better to change the parameter to match the column. Show some actual code that demonstrates the problem you are seeing.